# Aproximating rational with fraction with "smallest numerator and denumerator possible"

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

For example $0.795=\frac{159}{200}$. But is there a way to find fraction with smaller numerator and denumerator that will represent number $0.795xyz...$ i.e. it will approximate our given number?

I need algorithm or some procedure for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest denominator $q$ is $q=44$ corresponding to $$\frac pq=\frac{35}{44}=0.795\overline{45}$$
To see this, note that
$$ \frac ab=\frac{31}{39}=0.79487\ldots$$
is too small and
$$\frac cd=\frac{4}{5}=0.8$$
is too big.
For any fraction with $\frac ab<\frac pq<\frac cd$, we have
$$\frac pq-\frac ab=\frac{bp-aq}{bq}>0\qquad\frac cd-\frac pq=\frac{cq-dp}{dq}>0,$$
hence $$ bp-aq\ge 1\qquad cq-dp\ge 1$$
and finally (because $bc-ad=1$)
$$ q=(bc-ad)q=d(bp-aq)+b(cq-dp)\ge b+d=44.$$

Answer (score 4):

This is solved with [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  Your specific example $0.795$ is the continued fraction $[0;1,3,1,7,5]$.  It has convergents (best approximations) $0,1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\frac{31}{39},\frac{159}{200}$.

$\frac{4}{5}=0.8$ is pretty good, and $\frac{31}{39}=0.7948718\ldots$ is even better.

Comment: but what if I want this 0.795... not 0.794? I need first 3 decimal places to be exact.

Comment: @Mare, $31/39$ *is* $0.795$ to three decimal places, because $0.7948$ rounds to $0.795$.

Comment: Then modify the rounding. If you use $[0;1,3,1,8]$, you'll get $\frac{35}{44}$, which is 0.79545454... - it's a little further from exact, but still quite good.

Comment: @GlenO: that's what I was looking for =)